# How to align title at center of ActionBar in default theme(Theme.Holo.Light)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, alignment, center, title

I searched a lot but can not find a way, How can I set then title at center of ActionBar instead of left aligned. I used below code to set the title at center :

```
ViewGroup decorView= (ViewGroup) this.getWindow().getDecorView();
LinearLayout root= (LinearLayout) decorView.getChildAt(0);
FrameLayout titleContainer= (FrameLayout) root.getChildAt(0);
TextView title= (TextView) titleContainer.getChildAt(0);
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

But it gives error as below :

```
ClassCastException : com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView can not 
be cast to android.widget.TextView.
```

Any other solution ..Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to mimmick iOS design on Android? Because you really shouldn't :)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can create a custom layout and apply it to the actionBar.

To do so, follow those 2 simple steps:

1. **Java Code**

   ```
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
   getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
   ```

Where `R.layout.actionbar` is the following layout.

2. **XML**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:orientation="vertical">

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
       android:text="YOUR ACTIVITY TITLE"
       android:textColor="#ffffff"
       android:textSize="24sp" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

It can be as complex as you want. Try it out!

EDIT:

To set the `background` you can use the property `android:background` in the container layout (LinearLayout in that case). You may need to set the layout height `android:layout_height` to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.

Moreover, you can also add a **LOGO** / **ICON** to it. To do so, simply add an **ImageView** inside your layout, and set layout orientation property `android:orientation` to horizontal (or simply use a RelativeLayout and manage it by yourself).

To change the title of above custom action bar dynamically, do this:

```
TextView title=(TextView)findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", getPackageName()));
title.setText("Your Text Here");
```

Comment: It works perfect but It uses Custom Display..And I am using Theme.Holo.Light..So All the Logo with image, background color and Backbutton are removed and only simple white color title bar is displayed at center of ActionBar.Is there any way to display it at center on my current theme ? Thanks.

Comment: No your second answer didnt work ..It says FrameLayout can not be resolved to type.

Comment: It works perfect but It uses Custom Display..And I am using Theme.Holo.Light..So All the Logo with image, background color and Backbutton are removed and only simple white color title bar is displayed at center of ActionBar.

Comment: I want to use this feature in Default theme.I dont want to use it in ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM..So it didn't work.

Comment: @PaulBurke :Can I set textView's text(Title) from Activity?

Comment: @StefanoMunarini :Can I set textView's text(Title) from Activity?

Comment: Nice hack, thanks! But there is a little problem with this. When the app launches it shows the action bar with the title text on the left side, but the "actionbar.xml" gets aplied only after a few seconds which is not too nice. I thare a way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Hey @EdmondTamas I think you can try inflating a layout directly in the XML where you define the style of your app, "overriding" the default ActionBar style!

Comment: Thanks @StefanoMunarini for the suggestion. This was my initial thought, I need only to center the text and maybe to add a logo...I would like to keep it simple, but I can't find anything on overriding the default XML style. Look: [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131388/centring-the-title-on-the-andorid-anctionbar-using-the-style-xml-possible)

Comment: Doesn't work: Textview remains right next to the navigation menu item.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere have you tried with a RelativeLayout instead?

Comment: What worked was to set the layout programmatically, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21770534/550471

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere that's weird! U sure you put "width" to matchparent and not to wrap content? For me that worked!

Comment: missing navigation drawer icon by using this ?
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 

any hint to have custom bar with menu icon also

Comment: Hey, @StefanoMunarini! I use a custom view for the `ActionBar`. My only problem is that I wish to add menu items in the `ActionBar`. When I do so, the custom view is resized and and my center aligned logo shifts to the left. Got a fix for this?

Comment: Be sure to use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);` if you are using the support `ActionBar`. Using only `ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM` might show a red compile error if not.

Comment: If there is an action button on the left or right, the text won't be aligned to center.

Comment: What to do if I want to add title and logo in a fragment and the title of the fragment changes dynamically with regards to the page. I have tried `TextView title=(TextView)findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", getPackageName()));
title.setText("Your Text Here");` but error shows in the getPackage(); method

Comment: This won't work, you have to provide `LayoutParams` as well in `setCustomView` method

Answer (score 8):

It seems there is no way to do this without custom view. You can get the title view:

```
View decor = getWindow().getDecorView();
TextView title = (TextView) decor.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android"));
```

But changing of `gravity` or `layout_gravity` doesn't have an effect. 
The problem in the `ActionBarView`, which layout its children by itself so changing of layout params of its children also doesn't have an effect.
To see this excecute following code:

```
ViewGroup actionBar = (ViewGroup) decor.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar", "id", "android"));
View v = actionBar.getChildAt(0);
ActionBar.LayoutParams p = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
p.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;
v.setLayoutParams(p);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: nullpointer exception for actionBar
Apptheme is DarkActionBar

Answer (score 7):

Check out new Tool bar on support library class in  Lollipop update you can design actionbar by adding toolbar in your layout

add these items in your app theme

```
 <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Create your toolbar in a layout and include your textview in center design your toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/acbarcolor">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

add your action bar as tool bar

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

please ensure that you need to include toolbar on your resource file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                layout="@layout/homepageinc" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:name="com.shouldeye.homepages.HomeFragment"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

I know my answer is not on time but this is purely code no `xml` required.

This is for use in  `Activity`

```
public void setTitle(String title){
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(title);
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(textView);
}
```

This is for use in `Fragment`

```
public void setTitle(String title){
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    textView.setText(title);
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(textView);
}
```

Comment: Super simple to implement and extremely easy to customize. Nice!

Answer (score 4):

if You are Using Toolbar the just Add

`android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

Under the Toolbar Just like this snippet

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"    //Important 
            android:textColor="@color/whitecolor"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Hope it will Help You Guys if You are Using Toolbar  :)

Answer (score 3):

This actually works:

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
 getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
  ActionBar.LayoutParams p = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        p.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

You have to define custom_actionbar.xml layout which is as per your requirement e.g. :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#2e2e2e"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/top_banner"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think by positioning views on action bar you will reach what you want.On action bar's layout when layout params set to match parent it does not match full width
that's why I did it programmatically where I succeed.By setting width (it works like layout_weight="value") we can set our view wherever we want:

```
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); 
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); 

    LayoutInflater ll = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) ll.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    //inner layout within above linear layout
    LinearLayout inner = (LinearLayout) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.inner_linear_ractionbar);
    inner.setMinimumWidth(getWidth() * 2 / 10);
    // we will set our textview to center and display there some text
    TextView t = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.center_text);
    t.setWidth(getWidth() * 6 / 10);


    Button b = (Button) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_button);
    b.setWidth(getWidth() *3/ 20);

    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_delete_item);
    imageButton.setMinimumWidth(deviceUtils.getWidth() / 20);
```

and here is getWidth() method:

```
 public int getWidth() { 
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
     mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    return dm.widthPixels; 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Java code:
write this in onCreate()
`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);`
`getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);`

and for you custom view, simply use FrameLayout, east peasy!
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar is another option

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and because of the "Home" button added automatically in the toolbar, my text was not exactly entered.

I fixed it the dirty way but it works well in my case. I simply added a margin to the right of my TextView to compensate for the home button on the left. Here's my toolbar layout :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/mainBackgroundColor"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <com.lunabee.common.utils.LunabeeShadowTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/navigation.toolbar.title" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force the toolbar by wrapping title and level right padding which has default left padding for title. Than put background color to the parent of toolbar and that way part which is cut out by wrapping title is in the same color(white in my example):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="56dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:paddingEnd="15dp"
           android:paddingRight="15dp"
           android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
           app:titleTextColor="@color/black"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

solution is based on these things:

- you need to use your own class that extends Toolbar (support.v7.widget.toolbar)
- you need to override one method Toolbar#addView

what does it do:

when first time toolbar is executing #setTitle, it creates AppCompatTextView and uses it to display title text.

when the AppCompatTextView is created, toolbar (as ViewGroup), adds it into it's own hierarchy with #addView method.

also, while trying to find solution i noticed that the textview has layout width set to "wrap_content", so i decided to make it "match_parent" and assign textalignment to "center".

MyToolbar.kt, skipping unrelated stuff (constructors/imports):

```
class MyToolbar : Toolbar {

  override fun addView(child: View, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams) {
    if (child is TextView) {
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        child.textAlignment= View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
    }
    super.addView(child, params)
  }
}
```

possible "side effects" - this will apply to "subtitle" too

Answer (score 0):

After two days of going through the web, this is what I came up with in Kotlin. Tested and works on my app

```
  private fun setupActionBar() {
    supportActionBar?.apply {
        displayOptions = ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
        displayOptions = ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE
        setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
        title = ""


        val titleTextView = AppCompatTextView(this@MainActivity)
        titleTextView.text = getText(R.string.app_name)
        titleTextView.setSingleLine()
        titleTextView.textSize = 24f
        titleTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, R.color.appWhite))

        val layoutParams = ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        setCustomView(titleTextView, layoutParams)

        setBackgroundDrawable(
            ColorDrawable(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    R.color.appDarkBlue
                )
            )
        )

    }
}
```