# How to Center Text in Action bar Android?

Tags: android

i am customizing my Action bar using styles. I am using custom style and setting it to the application tag in manifest.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/action_bar_title_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/cross_pattern</item>
</style>

<style name="action_bar_title_text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_title_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/action_bar_title_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

I am setting the title in the action bar also. Is there any way to center align the text ?

The issue is that i know how to do it via custom views, but i have to do it by styles.

I really don't understand the reason for downvoting. I thought that if you can change background style of action bar using custom style's so i thought that maybe you can align the text in Action bar to center. I have tried it myself first, but i was unsuccessful so  i asked it here then i asked question here. I think it is a good question.

Instead of answers , my question is only getting downvoted.

Comment: Not possible out of the box AND this is an anti pattern. I think you have to create a custom action bar view or text view inside the actionbar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418635/how-to-align-title-at-center-of-actionbar-in-default-themetheme-holo-light

Comment: Did you try by putting android:layout_width="match_parent" to your action_bar_title_text style?

Comment: please kindly post the reason for downvoting

Comment: I really don't understand the reason for downvoting. I thought taht you can change background style of action bas using custom style so i thought that maybe you can align the text in Action bar to center. I have tried myself first, then i asked question here. I think it is a good question

Answer (score 0):

You can download [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manuelmaly.hn) app from Google Play. It is a Hacker News app. Also, you can find what you're looking for in [this](https://github.com/manmal/hn-android) repository.

Hope it helps! :D

Answer (score -5):

I think it's

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Try it and tell me if it's okay