# How can I center align my header text in Android?

Tags: android

```
  <application
      android:name="com.example.ma01_gt_gpro_1.GlobalClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/gproicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ma01_gt_gpro_1.MG00LoginForm"  
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="MG03Navigation" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
    <activity android:name="MG02DataSynchronize" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
    <activity android:name="MG02DataSynchronize1" ></activity>
    <activity android:name="MG01MainForm" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
    <activity android:name="MT01ASalesOrderView" android:noHistory="true"></activity>

    <activity android:name="MT01_B_ListParty" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
    <activity android:name="MT01_C_ListItems" ></activity>
    <activity android:name="MT02_A_ListParty" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
    <activity android:name="MT02_B_ListPaymentMode" ></activity>
     <activity android:name="MT01SalesOrder" android:label="                            SALES ORDER"></activity>
    <activity android:name="MT02CollectionEntry" android:label="                            COLLECTION"></activity>
    <activity android:name="MT02_C_CollectionReport" android:label="                            COLLECTION REPORT"></activity>
    <activity android:name="MR01SalesOrderReport" android:label="                           SALESORDER REPORT" ></activity>

</application>
```

Here I  found an temporary solution `android:label="SALESORDER REPORT" >`

But it won't get work with large screens

Comment: What you actualy want to do ,can you explain little more??

Comment: In my application i try to set an header by android:label but it gives an output as left alignment as default.how can i make it as center .

Comment: Are you using ActionBar in your app??

Comment: yes.I searched google a lot .,but i could'nt get a solution  exactly

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align title at center of ActionBar in default theme(Theme.Holo.Light)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418635/how-to-align-title-at-center-of-actionbar-in-default-themetheme-holo-light)

Comment: yes @Voicu's response is right . You can change with way

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Remove ActionBar.

Step 2: Take some TextView with align parent_top.

Step 3: And place your Activity name on that textview programmatically.

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who supported me ?

i Found an solution:

[How to center align the ActionBar title in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-center-align-the-actionbar-title-in-android)

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);