# Android: Action bar's action items centered

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I am working on the action bar of an application and I want the actions to be centered. I searched everywhere but all I can find is how to center the title. Is there anyway to center the actions? Moreover, I would like the text of the actions to be below the icon not on the right of the icon. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Refer this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418635/how-to-align-title-at-center-of-actionbar-in-default-themetheme-holo-light

Comment: I don't want to center the title. I want to center the actions

Comment: It may not be the answer you're looking for but you can use a custom view instead of actionbar or toolbar! It may take some time but it gives you full flexibility!