# How to set the title at center in android status bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, statusbar

I changed tha status bar's color from styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<color name="custom_theme_color">#42A5F5</color>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I also change the status bar's title from string.xml:

```
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Qu-easy</string>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</resources>
```

How can i set the title to the center of status bar?
I guess something like gravity.center?

Comment: Make custome Action bar about this and than cener the title refer this accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418635/how-to-align-title-at-center-of-actionbar-in-default-themetheme-holo-light

Answer (score 0):

try this one :-
Here you need to add one xml file
write following code in `onCreate` method

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
ActionBar.LayoutParams p = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
p.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

**custom_actionbar.xml Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="XYZ"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This will definitely work for you

Comment: I dont use an action bar,just a status bar

Comment: as per my knowledge status bar is nothing but the action bar. both having same functionality.
and here you can also make center text by editing your theme.
and you can take `ActionBarActivity` for your action bar