# How to align Title in center of Actionbar with back button in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am trying to make a title bar of actionbar in the center ,
I tried the code to make it center but no success
my code inside fragment `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.toobar_center_withback); ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

my xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="SIGN IN"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

it gives output [image]
I also tried some margin to textview but how can I know the actual margin measurement for different screen

I followed these solutions but no success

[How to align title at center of ActionBar in default theme(Theme.Holo.Light)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418635/how-to-align-title-at-center-of-actionbar-in-default-themetheme-holo-light)

Another thing is that I dont want to use any toolbar or something else ,I want a simple solution for all fragments

I also written the code but no success

```
 public void setTitle(String title) {
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    textView.setText(title);
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(textView);
}
```

It works fine when I have no button or have backbutton and also have a button in menu with showaction always like this

[image]

Comment: i think, your textview is inflated after the back button. thats why it counts your toolbar after the default up button. So, basically you r using the gravity right and its working.. but its parent layout starts at just after the up button...thats why it is.. and when you add the button in toolbar it shifts the text to left(according to the button width).

Comment: Actually I am using fragments and I am also changed the default behaviour of backbutton so for that I am calling ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); after settile

Comment: doesn't matter if you are using fragment or not.. its not related.. its just about the views and its bounds. its not a problem.. up button is just taking its space.. and rest is for your text view title.

Comment: so whats the solution

Comment: it has nothing like solution.. it can be done by tricks.. just add the padding_right/margin_right to your textview (padding==up button size).

Comment: well you rounded my mind , I already said in my question I applied some margin too but since backbutton different in different devices so how can I give textview a margin

Comment: so how much margin should I provide to textview

Comment: add a custom back drawable as back button(just one line of code).
now you have a drawable and you can get the size... as i previously said.. its a trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally I found a trick to tackle this problem and it worked

```
setTitle("Sign In");
 ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

here is my setTitle method

```
 public void setTitle(String title) {
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    textView.setText(title);
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(textView);
}
```

and here I created a menu item with transparent image

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.blank_menu,menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

here is my blank_menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
<item
    android:title="   "
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:icon="@drawable/transparent"
    >
</item>
</menu>
```

and now its giving output like this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem too then I found the solution in:

1.Create custom toolbar `custom_actionbar.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_action_bar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

2.Disable default actionbar using

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

3.Then include this `custom_actionbar` in each layout

```
<include layout="@layout/custom_actionbar"/>
```

Comment: did you read my question correctly , I actually said I dont want to use any toolbar

Comment: @UmarAta but you cannot do without using toolbar

Comment: My answer is quite relevant and work for your problem

Comment: I clearly mentioned in my question that I don't want to use any toolbar since my project is working and I can't change all the activities and fragments behavior , everthing is working fine even I am also getting fragment from backstack with proper text tile except of their center alignment problem so , I can't change the code of whole project